# How to get MatchAllFilter to work properly and add other filters to MatchAllfilter?

Tags: java, list, class, filter, filtering

I do not think the MatchAllFilter class that I have created is storing the filters I am trying to add to it properly. When I pass a list in none of the filters are working. How do I properly store other filters into MatchAllFitlers and have the filters stored inside maf filter the lists I will be passing? I have tested all my filters one by one; I know they work.

```
public class MatchAllFilter implements Filter {
 private ArrayList<Filter>filt;
 private String nameF;
 public MatchAllFilter(){
     filt= new ArrayList<Filter>();


    }
public void addFilter(Filter f){
    filt.add(f);


}

public boolean satisfies(QuakeEntry qe) { 
    for(Filter f:filt){
        if (f.satisfies(qe)){
            return true;

        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

}

```
 public void testMatchAllFilter(){
    EarthQuakeParser parser = new EarthQuakeParser(); 
    //String source = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_week.atom";
    String source = "data/nov20quakedatasmall.atom";
    ArrayList<QuakeEntry> list  = parser.read(source);  
    MatchAllFilter maf=new MatchAllFilter();
    double depthMin=-100000.0;
    double depthMax=-10000.0;
    Filter f=  new DepthFilter(-100000.0,-10000.0);
    maf.addFilter(f);
    Filter e= new MagnitudeFilter(0.0, 2.0);
    maf.addFilter(e);
    Filter g= new PhraseFilter("any","a");
    maf.addFilter(g);

    //ArrayList<QuakeEntry>m10= filter(list,maf);       
    //for (QuakeEntry qe: list) { 
        //System.out.println(qe);
    System.out.println(maf);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is check if all the filters in `filt` are applicable to `qe` then the problem is that right now you are checking if `any` of the filters satisfy its criteria and then exiting the function. In other words, instead off ***all*** filters you are checking for ***any*** filters. e.g.:

```
public boolean satisfies(QuakeEntry qe) { 
    for(Filter f : filt) {
        if (f.satisfies(qe)) { // one of the filters worked, let's exit
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you need to check if all filters apply to `qe` then you have to traverse through the whole list of filters in `filt`

```
public boolean satisfies(QuakeEntry qe) { 
    for(Filter f : filt){
        if (!f.satisfies(qe)) { // any of the filters criteria failed, then exit
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // the code will only reach this point if all the filters were applied
}
```

If you are using **Java 8+**, you can use `streams` e.g.

```
public boolean satisfies(QuakeEntry qe) { 
    return filt.stream().allMatch(f -> f.satisfies(qe));
}
```

Comment: I realized I do not need the for loop in my test because the filter already has a for loop. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Elizabeth gotcha. Glad I could help!